# Bootstrap Pills and Background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, background

I am creating my first Bootstrap/CSS site and have run into trouble with the navigation.
I wanted the background to the nav section to be white with the standard Bootstrap Pills.
But all I get is the page names in a nice neat row but no 'pill' around them and the page background has remained unchanged.
What am I doing wrong?

HTML CODE IS AS FOLLOWS

```
<div class="nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

<li><a href="About.htm">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="HoP.htm">HOME of PEACE</a></li>
<li><a href="update.htm">NEWS UPDATE</a></li> 
<li><a href="Pastnews.htm">PREVIOUS NEWSLETER</a></li> 
<li><a href="Sponsor.htm">SUPPORT the WORK</a></li> 
<li><a href="giftaid.htm">GIFT AID</a></li> 
<li><a href="Contact.htm">CONTACT</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
```

CSS STYLESHEET IS AS FOLLOWS

.

```
nav background {
color: white;
}
.nav a {
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;

}
.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: The background is added when they have an `.active` class on them.

Comment: Sorry where do I put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is a little malformed.  Try the following.

```
.nav {
    background: white;
}
.nav a {
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
}
```

Then you can change the colors for the `:hover` and `.active` states like this

```
.nav > li > a.active {
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li.active > a:hover {
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: OK I did as you suggested but sadly nothing changed. Still no white background to the nav strip, still no Bootstrap Pills around each item. New Css code is .nav { background: white;
}
.nav a {
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  
  
}
.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

Comment: Here's an example of the code running and working  http://www.bootply.com/8oPKpLDOyw

Comment: I have just seen the comment about .hover and .active. Thank you. I added your code to my css and even though it has not changed the background when I hover over a link it get a coloured box background. That is a real improvement but it would still be nice to have that strip on a white background with lovely Bootstrap Pill shaped buttons for each link.

Comment: This updated one shows the same CSS code working with a black background on the body.  http://www.bootply.com/VmFfh81gBM  You might need to make sure you're setting the `background: white;` on the `.nav` container like in the example above.

Comment: Progress. I removed the .nav background and added it under the .nav li section. Now just missing the 'pills'

Comment: Ding. I looked at your example and it is good. Could my problem be because my nav bar is not at the top of the page but below the section where we have our brand name and before the main content section?  UPDATE. After posting this I tried moving it to the top of the page but it did not change anything so I put it back where we wanted it to be.

Comment: It sounds like the style rule is being overridden by something else.  If you're using Chrome you could check in Developer Tools and check the styling of the elements with the inspect element tool to see what is overriding it.

Comment: Thanks Ding you have been a great help